# Executing a tasklet after an ItemWriter

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

My purpose of this batch job is to fetch few documents from the DB, encrypt it and sftp it to a server. For this I am using item readers and writers. For encryption, I should use a tasklet which is in a jar(I don't own the source code). There are millions of records to be processed, so I am using some chunk-interval for reading and writing it. My problem is during encyrption(while calling the tasklet after every chunk of writing is complete).

Is there a way to call the tasklet after writer (in batch:chunk) ?

As of now, I am doing the following:

```
<batch:job id="batchJob">
        <batch:step id="prepareStep" next="encryptStep">
             <batch:tasklet task-executor="executor">
                <batch:chunk reader="reader" processor="processor"
                    writer="writer" commit-interval="100" >
                    </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="encryptStep" next="uploadStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="encryptTasklet" />
        </batch:step>
```

But the problem in the above approach is that only after reading, processing and writing all the million records only then encryptStep is called. `But I want it to work in chunks, that is, execute encryptTasklet after every chunk write is executed.` Is there a way to achieve this?

Please help.

Comment: You can't call a tasklet directly (in a listener, for example) because tasklet is SB component and owns a specific lifecycle.
Is there any (un)official way to call the encryption code used inside tasklet directly from your processor?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Thanks for your comment. I was thinking the same, if I can call execute method directly then I will be bypassing somethings in its lifecycle. I have another way to achieve my purpose - to replace reader, processor and writer with a task let and loop through the input file. In this case my chunk-interval will be 1. I don't mind implementing this if it works without any issues. your comments?

Comment: You can use spring partitioner to make more threads run parallely and completing the job quickly. For each partition you can put condition is sql to fetch data may be on date range or something else which can partition db data on different subset and then run each subset parallely.

Comment: @AmitKBist Thanks for your response. My query is , how to execute a task let after every chunk completion.

Comment: @Arun: I gave parallely processing reply to your processing chunk interval - 1 comment, by implementing parallel processing you will able to process multiple records in different threads. Another solution to your tasklet issue will be - You can write own custom writer and add that tasklet task inside the writer, that way tasklet will be called when writer finishes that chunk.

Comment: @AmitKBist I don't have the source code of the tasklet, as I don't own it. It is a dependency jar.

Comment: @Arun, You don't need tasklet source code, you can simply call that class and appropriate method from the custom writer.

Comment: @AmitKBist I finally did that . Is there a better way?

Comment: I cannot think of a better way of calling your tasklet inside chunk.